# Want to know how to write anything on file through program in win32 application

Tags: c, winapi

i am a beginner and want to file handling concept in win32 application for writing anything say text in file which is present in some location on hard disk.

Please Reply

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Any good book on C will have a chapter on file I/O, if it does not have to be win32 specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in this way
Suppose there is a folder called "XYZ" at "E:" drive & the file name is "abc.log" and the 
function which u call is say "WSL".

```
VOID __cdecl WSL(char *message);//function declaration
```

//Function definition:

```
VOID __cdecl WSL(char *message) 
{ 
   static int lineNo = 1;  
   FILE *fp = fopen("E:\\XYZ\\abc.log","a+");  
   if(fp!= NULL)  
   {   
        fprintf(fp,"%d : %s\n",lineNo++,message);   
        fclose(fp);
   } 
}
```

and at main function u r coding the following:

```
int main()
{
  FILE *fp = fopen("E:\\XYZ\\abc.log","w");
  WSL("Application opened");
  ........
  ........
  ........
  ........
  ........
  WSL("Application closed");
}
```

This will write two time at abc.log file since it is called twice in your main function.

First time it will print...

> **1. Application opened**

& second time it will print

> **2. Application closed**

Comment: There are other various method to obtain this. Choice is yours.

Comment: Nit: the mode for `fopen` need not be "a+": you never read from the file inside the WSL function. And you should either open the file inside the function (and close it before the function returns) or once in `main`, pass the handle to the function, and close the file in main.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do that.
1. Use functions fopen(), fwrite(), fclose()
2. Use std::fstream

Answer (score 1):

Use fstream to write to a file, rather than win32 API. This is for RAII reasons, and it is also more standard.

Comment: Ok i will try in that way too. But  the above example worked nicely at my desk.
Thanks